# Selecting Availability Zone for RDS Read Replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I wanted to **create a read replica** of an existing RDS instance via AWS Websites.

However, I don't see option for selecting **Availability Zone**.

How can I configure RDS read-replica for **specific availability zone?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console seems to use the default option and that's it. Which means a randon az in the region.
You can create one in a specific Availability zone with `aws cli`.
The command to do it is

```
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica \
    --db-instance-identifier myreadreplica \
    --source-db-instance-identifier mydbinstance \
    --availability-zone mychosenaz
```

You can add other options to the command as you like.
More information can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance-read-replica.html).